# Detect unnamed repository is malformed

Tags: shiny

I need help to figure out this error when I run my shiny app

shiny::runApp('C:/citibike-analysis')
Error in read.dcf(con) :
  Line starting 'Unnamed repository;  ...' is malformed!

Answer (score 1):

Did you, by any chance, copy *all* the contents of a git repository flatly into `/srv/shiny-server/[app-name]`? I just did that using Docker's `COPY` command and had the exact same error message.

If that's the problem, I solved it with just copying the `*.R` and `*.Rmd` files from the git repository into the app folder.